# How to enforce xmlforest creat elements even if expression value is null?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I would like to use the oracle `XMLFOREST` function. ([Link for definition](http://psoug.org/definition/XMLFOREST.htm))

Example Syntax:

> ```
> XMLFOREST( [value expression AS alias], [...])
> ```

My problem is that if value expression is NULL, then no element is created for that value expression.

How can I enforce it to add an empty XML fragment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can' use [`XMLFOREST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions244.htm#i1172404):

> If value_expr is null, then no element is created for that value_expr.

Nor the similar [`XMLCOLATTVAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions238.htm#i1129374) function:

> You must specify a value for value_expr. If value_expr is null, then no element is returned.

[`XMLELEMENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions242.htm#i1129193) on the other hand returns an empty element as requested:

```
SQL> select xmlelement("EMP", xmlelement("ENAME", ename), 
  2                           xmlelement("JOB", job),
  3                           xmlelement("MGR", mgr)
  4         ).getclobval() xml
  5    from scott.emp;

XML
----------------------------------------------------------------
<EMP><ENAME>KING</ENAME><JOB>PRESIDENT</JOB><MGR></MGR></EMP>
<EMP><ENAME>BLAKE</ENAME><JOB>MANAGER</JOB><MGR>7839</MGR></EMP>
...
```

---

For completeness, two more Oracle tools can also be used (inspired by [this post on the OTN forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9390037)). First you can use an [`XMLQUERY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions249.htm#CIHHFFGG) (on 11.2? ):

```
SQL> select
  2    xmlquery(
  3     '(#ora:view_on_null empty #) {
  4      <EMPS> {
  5          for $c in fn:collection("oradb:/SCOTT/EMP")/ROW
  6          return element EMP {
  7            $c/ENAME
  8          , $c/JOB
  9          , $c/MGR
 10       }
 11      }</EMPS>
 12     }'
 13    passing cast(10 as number) as "mid"
 14    returning content
 15  ).getClobval() as result
 16  from dual;

RESULT 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
<EMPS>
   <EMP><ENAME>KING</ENAME><JOB>PRESIDENT</JOB><MGR></MGR></EMP>
   <EMP><ENAME>BLAKE</ENAME>...
```

You can also use the [`DBMS_XMLGEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xmlgen.htm#i1012053) package:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    ctx    dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
  3    sqlstr varchar2(4000)
  4       := 'SELECT ename, job, mgr FROM scott.emp WHERE ename=''KING''';
  5    res    clob;
  6  BEGIN
  7    ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext(sqlstr);
  8    dbms_xmlgen.setNullHandling(ctx, dbms_xmlgen.EMPTY_TAG);
  9    res := dbms_xmlgen.getXML(ctx);
 10    dbms_xmlgen.closeContext(ctx);
 11    dbms_output.put_line(res);
 12  END;
 13  /

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ENAME>KING</ENAME>
  <JOB>PRESIDENT</JOB>
  <MGR/>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```