# The XML Tag doesn't appear when the Value is Null in the Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

How can I retrieve the XML tags when the field is NULL? This is the Query:

```
  SELECT XMLElement("FlowerSeeds" , XMLAttributes('http://euroconsumers.org/' as "xmlns")
           , xmlforest(
                       d.cli_pre_l "Name"
                       , d.cli_nom_l "FirstName"
                       , COALESCE(d.cli_gsm_c, NULL) "Phone"                       
                       , d.cli_eml_c "Email"
                       , 
                          xmlforest (
                                           d.cli_rue_l "Street"
                                           , d.CLI_RUE_NUM_L "StreetNumber"
                                           , d.cli_cpo_c "PostalCode"
                                           , d.cli_loc_l "City"
                                           , null as "District"
                           ) "DeliveryAddress"
                      )
                  ).getclobval()
  FROM TA_MAIN.clients d
 WHERE d.cli_id_s = 2504217
```

I have a problem when some field is NULL, the tag of XML is not generated.

For example: When the value of Phone or Email is NULL, the XML tag is not generated. How can I create XML tag even when the value is null?

Like this:

```
<FlowerSeeds xmlns="http://euroconsumers.org/">
    <Name>SYLVIA</Name>
    <FirstName>DEL</FirstName>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <Street>AVENUE DE ROG 135</Street>
        <StreetNumber>135</StreetNumber>
        <PostalCode>1285</PostalCode>
        <City>WOLUWE</City>
    </DeliveryAddress>
</FlowerSeeds>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enforce xmlforest creat elements even if expression value is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705800/how-to-enforce-xmlforest-creat-elements-even-if-expression-value-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is the next query:

```
 SELECT XMLElement("FlowerSeeds" , XMLAttributes('http://euroconsumers.org/' as "xmlns")
         , XMLElement("Name", d.cli_pre_l)
         , XMLElement("FirstName", d.cli_nom_l)
         , XMLElement("GSM1", d.cli_gsm_c)
         , XMLElement("Email", d.cli_eml_c)        
         , XMLElement(
                      "DeliveryAddress", 
                       XMLElement("Street", d.cli_rue_l)
                       , XMLElement("StreetNumber", d.CLI_RUE_NUM_L)
                       , XMLElement("PostalCode", d.cli_cpo_c)
                       , XMLElement("City", d.cli_loc_l)
                       , XMLElement("District", NULL)
                     )
       ).getclobval()
  FROM TA_MAIN.clients d
 WHERE d.cli_id_s = 2504217
```