# XML web service not showing empty fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, sqlite

I'm developing a web service in .NET (C#) which shows in a XML the results of a SQL query. The query is:

```
return dbContext.data
.SqlQuery("SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g FROM person").ToList();
```

Let's say now that fields `f` and `g` are `null` in my database. In my web service I get this:

```
<person>
<a>'LU'</a>
<b>'1'</b>
<c>'JOHN'</c>
<d>'1'</d>
<e>'REP1'</e>
</person>
```

As you can see, fields `f` and `g` are not showing in the XML result. Since I'm inserting this data into an SQLite database I would like to get ALSO the empty/null fields, so the database structure still the same. I would like something like that:

```
<person>
<a>'LU'</a>
<b>'1'</b>
<c>'JOHN'</c>
<d>'1'</d>
<e>'REP1'</e>
<f></f>
<g></g>
</person>
```

Before posting here, I've tried using `ISNULL` in my SQL query:

```
return dbContext.data
.SqlQuery("SELECT a, b, c, d, e, ISNULL(f, null) as f, ISNULL(g,null) as g FROM person").ToList();
```

But it's not working. Any idea of how can I get all the fields in the XML even when they are empty or null?

Comment: I will translate your ISNULL usage: `if f is null then null`. What you need is empty sting in second parameter of ISNULL method...I guess :)

Comment: What if `f` is an INTEGER instead of an String?

Comment: Use -1 to represent null; cast f to string, return empty string or 'NULL' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLELEMENT it returns an empty element as requested:

Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705800/how-to-enforce-xmlforest-creat-elements-even-if-expression-value-is-null)

```
SQL> select xmlelement("EMP", xmlelement("ENAME", ename), 
                            xmlelement("JOB", job),
                            xmlelement("MGR", mgr)
          ).getclobval() xml
     from scott.emp;

XML
----------------------------------------------------------------
<EMP><ENAME>KING</ENAME><JOB>PRESIDENT</JOB><MGR></MGR></EMP>
<EMP><ENAME>BLAKE</ENAME><JOB>MANAGER</JOB><MGR>7839</MGR></EMP>
...
```